# How can I recover overwritten files?

Tags: windows-7

I have a few files that I accidently updated without making a backup first. I transferred (instead of copying) them to another folder and ended up overwriting the data. Is there any way to restore the files to an earlier point if Volume Shadow Copy isn't enabled?

Comment: @Scott: Unless I'm mistaken, those programs only work when the actual data hasn't been wiped. When you delete a file, its entry is removed from the master file table, but the actual data still exists. What I've done is actually overwrite the data. I need driver-level code at the very least. Also, I hope I wasn't downvoted because of that :/.

Comment: i would suspect overwriting your file with a new file is essentially removing the file and creating a new one, except if you actually opened the file and changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Piriform makes a program called Recuva, I have recovered some deleted files I thought were gone.  It might work for you.

[Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Comment: Sadly Recuva didn't work.

Comment: @someguy if you ran it to no avail, if you run more things it will just become more difficult to recover. You need to decide how much the data is worth